# Visual Studio 2022 - Lots of errors in TypeScript Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio

Yesterday I created a new `Standalone TypeScript Angular Project` in `Visual Studio 2022`.

After a couple of minutes playing around with it, I already got a bunch of error messages from VisualStudio. The project itself works fine, my Angular App is working.

I'm usually getting around 200-300 errors. Restarting Visual Studio helps, but after a few minutes these errors appear again.

**Does anybody know what's causing this?**

Here's a trimmed list of the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS6053  File 'c:/_Spielwiese/test7/Frontend/node_modules/rxjs/index.d.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation Frontend JavaScript Content Files       1   Active
Error   TS6053  File 'c:/_Spielwiese/test7/Frontend/node_modules/jsonc-parser/lib/umd/main' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation Frontend JavaScript Content Files       1   Active
Error   TS2717  (TS) Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'signalCode' must be of type 'Signals', but here has type 'number'.    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\child_process.d.ts   22  Active
Error   TS2300  (TS) Duplicate identifier 'TranscodeEncoding'.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\buffer.d.ts  11  Active
Error   TS2300  (TS) Duplicate identifier 'SocketConnectOpts'.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\net.d.ts 61  Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: statSync, lstatSync, Type, PathLike, NoParamCallback, Stats, Dirent, Dir, ReadStream, WriteStream, WriteFileOptions, F_OK, R_OK, W_OK, X_OK, COPYFILE_EXCL, COPYFILE_FICLONE, COPYFILE_FICLONE_FORCE, O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR, O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_TRUNC, O_APPEND, O_DIRECTORY, O_NOATIME, O_NOFOLLOW, O_SYNC, O_DSYNC, O_SYMLINK, O_DIRECT, O_NONBLOCK, S_IFMT, S_IFREG, S_IFDIR, S_IFCHR, S_IFBLK, S_IFIFO, S_IFLNK, S_IFSOCK, S_IRWXU, S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR, S_IXUSR, S_IRWXG, S_IRGRP, S_IWGRP, S_IXGRP, S_IRWXO, S_IROTH, S_IWOTH, S_IXOTH, UV_FS_O_FILEMAP    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\fs.d.ts  21  Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: statSync, lstatSync, Type, PathLike, NoParamCallback, Stats, Dirent, Dir, ReadStream, WriteStream, WriteFileOptions, F_OK, R_OK, W_OK, X_OK, COPYFILE_EXCL, COPYFILE_FICLONE, COPYFILE_FICLONE_FORCE, O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR, O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_TRUNC, O_APPEND, O_DIRECTORY, O_NOATIME, O_NOFOLLOW, O_SYNC, O_DSYNC, O_SYMLINK, O_DIRECT, O_NONBLOCK, S_IFMT, S_IFREG, S_IFDIR, S_IFCHR, S_IFBLK, S_IFIFO, S_IFLNK, S_IFSOCK, S_IRWXU, S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR, S_IXUSR, S_IRWXG, S_IRGRP, S_IWGRP, S_IXGRP, S_IRWXO, S_IROTH, S_IWOTH, S_IXOTH, UV_FS_O_FILEMAP    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\fs.d.ts  1   Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ScriptId, RemoteObjectId, UnserializableValue, ExecutionContextId, Timestamp, UniqueDebuggerId, BreakpointId, CallFrameId, HeapSnapshotObjectId, WorkerID, SessionID, Session    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\inspector.d.ts   20  Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ScriptId, RemoteObjectId, UnserializableValue, ExecutionContextId, Timestamp, UniqueDebuggerId, BreakpointId, CallFrameId, HeapSnapshotObjectId, WorkerID, SessionID, Session    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\inspector.d.ts   13  Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: RequestListener, Server, OutgoingMessage, ServerResponse, ClientRequest, IncomingMessage, Agent, METHODS, STATUS_CODES, globalAgent, maxHeaderSize   Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\http.d.ts    42  Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: RequestListener, Server, OutgoingMessage, ServerResponse, ClientRequest, IncomingMessage, Agent, METHODS, STATUS_CODES, globalAgent, maxHeaderSize   Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\http.d.ts    1   Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: Base, WordArray, BufferedBlockAlgorithm, Hasher, Cipher, CipherParams, BlockCipherMode, SerializableCipher, PasswordBasedCipher, Pkcs7, AnsiX923, Iso10126, Iso97971, ZeroPadding, NoPadding, OpenSSL, CBC, CFB, CTR, CTRGladman, OFB, ECB, Hex, Latin1, Utf8, Utf16, Utf16BE, Utf16LE, Base64, Base64url, MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA224, SHA512, SHA384, SHA3, RIPEMD160, HMAC, PBKDF2, EvpKDF, AES, DES, TripleDES, RC4, RC4Drop, Rabbit, RabbitLegacy, Word, HmacMD5, HmacSHA1, HmacSHA256, HmacSHA224, HmacSHA512, HmacSHA384, HmacSHA3, HmacRIPEMD160   Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\crypto-js\index.d.ts  9   Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ADDRCONFIG, V4MAPPED, AnyRecordWithTtl, AnyRecord, NODATA, FORMERR, SERVFAIL, NOTFOUND, NOTIMP, REFUSED, BADQUERY, BADNAME, BADFAMILY, BADRESP, CONNREFUSED, TIMEOUT, EOF, FILE, NOMEM, DESTRUCTION, BADSTR, BADFLAGS, NONAME, BADHINTS, NOTINITIALIZED, LOADIPHLPAPI, ADDRGETNETWORKPARAMS, CANCELLED, Resolver Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\dns.d.ts 47  Active
Error   TS6200  (TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ADDRCONFIG, V4MAPPED, AnyRecordWithTtl, AnyRecord, NODATA, FORMERR, SERVFAIL, NOTFOUND, NOTIMP, REFUSED, BADQUERY, BADNAME, BADFAMILY, BADRESP, CONNREFUSED, TIMEOUT, EOF, FILE, NOMEM, DESTRUCTION, BADSTR, BADFLAGS, NONAME, BADHINTS, NOTINITIALIZED, LOADIPHLPAPI, ADDRGETNETWORKPARAMS, CANCELLED, Resolver Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\dns.d.ts 1   Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '__promisify__'.    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  70  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '__promisify__'.    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  86  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '__promisify__'.    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\globals.d.ts 179 Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '__promisify__'.    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\globals.d.ts 180 Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '__promisify__'.    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\globals.d.ts 187 Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '__promisify__'.    Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\globals.d.ts 188 Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'version'.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\punycode.d.ts    113 Active
    C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  24  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'setInterval'.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  8   Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'setImmediate'. Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  26  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'setImmediate'. Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  10  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'setImmediate'. Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  11  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'kStringMaxLength'. Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\buffer.d.ts  50  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'kStringMaxLength'. Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\buffer.d.ts  4   Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'kMaxLength'.   Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\buffer.d.ts  49  Active
Error   TS2451  (TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'kMaxLength'.   Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\buffer.d.ts  3   Active
C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\timers.d.ts  15  Active
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'AggregateErrorConstructor'.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\get-intrinsic\internal\intrinsics.d.ts    11  Active
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'AggregateError'. Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\get-intrinsic\internal\intrinsics.d.ts    126 Active
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'AggregateError'. Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\get-intrinsic\internal\intrinsics.d.ts    127 Active
Error   TS2687  (TS) All declarations of 'version' must have identical modifiers.   Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\process.d.ts 884 Active
Error   TS2687  (TS) All declarations of 'version' must have identical modifiers.   Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\globals.d.ts 1023    Active
Error   TS2687  (TS) All declarations of 'settings' must have identical modifiers.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\cluster.d.ts 336 Active
Error   TS2687  (TS) All declarations of 'arch' must have identical modifiers.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\kurka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.5\node_modules\@types\node\process.d.ts 1052    Active
Error   TS2687  (TS) All declarations of 'arch' must have identical modifiers.  Frontend JavaScript Content Files   C:\_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\node_modules\@types\node\globals.d.ts 1055    Active
```

Comment: That `C:_Spielwiese\test7\Frontend\ ` looks very suspect, as if a ` \ ` is missing after the drive letter somewhere in your project metadata.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I'm getting the same errors with correct paths on a different machine. I tried to use ```"exclude": "node_modules" in my tsconfig.json, but that has no effect